# How to call -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, drawrect

How Can i Call

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
```

in https://github.com/stkim1/MTImageMapView/blob/master/MTImageMapView/MTImageMapView.m

From Another `UiViewController` Periodically With `NSTimer`

Comment: Why you need to call drawrect() as its default method and will call automatically while initialize. Please specify why you need to call drawract() periodically ?

Comment: Do you have an instance of this map view in a UIView on your UIViewController?  Just call `setNeedsDisplay` on that view, and it will take care of the redraw.

You shouldn't access drawRect directly - it will be called by the controlling class as required

Comment: CodeChanger- Actually  I wanted To Show a Location  Marker in state, and i need To Update marker in to Another State with every second, i have made a logic to show a location marker and to which state it should go next but, can't  update the view

Comment: create one method and in that method you can change value of your marker and call `setNeedtoDisplay()` to redraw that view.

Comment: CodeChanger - i have tried that but     `setNeedtoDisplay()` isn't responding

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622529-drawrect):

> Discussion
>
> The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses
>   that use technologies such as Core Graphics and UIKit to draw their
>   view’s content should override this method and implement their drawing
>   code there. You do not need to override this method if your view sets
>   its content in other ways. For example, you do not need to override
>   this method if your view just displays a background color or if your
>   view sets its content directly using the underlying layer object.
>
> ...
>
> If you subclass `UIView` directly, your implementation of this method
>   does not need to call super. However, if you are subclassing a
>   different view class, you should call super at some point in your
>   implementation.
>
> This method is called when a view is first displayed or when an event
>   occurs that invalidates a visible part of the view. **You should never
>   call this method directly yourself**. To invalidate part of your view,
>   and thus cause that portion to be redrawn, call the `setNeedsDisplay` or
>   `setNeedsDisplayInRect:` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

YES i Found The solution i am calling a function with timer at the End of a `drawrect` function  and calling `setNeedsDisplay()`in it